# How to print the values from datatable(Arraylist) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a datatable in a JSP page and a print button. On click of the print button it will open the print option dialog and print the datatable values.

Now, I have `button onclick="callsubmit()"`.

javascript:

```
function callsubmit(){
    window.print();
    window.opener.document.location = window.opener.document.location.href;
    window.close();
}
```

This function prints the whole page, but I need datatable values only.

How to write javascript for print particular values?

Comment: Why not have the button open a window with a new JSP URL (e.g. printDatabaseValues.jsp), and have that window print itself with `window.print`?

Comment: How to open new jsp from button click ? It should be popup window, then this idea also looks good.

How to call new jsp page from javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Supply a separate CSS stylesheet on `media="print"` wherein you hide everything expect the table. E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" media="print">
```

wherein the `print.css` look like this:

```
#header, #menu, #footer, p {
    display: none;
}
```

This is of course only easy when your HTML is written [semantic](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/), else you'll have to bring some modifications in your HTML structure so that it's all nicely separated.

#### See also:

- [CSS Media Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)

Comment: How to open new jsp from button click ? It should be popup window, then this idea also looks good. How to call new jsp page from javascript ?

Comment: Just point to URL of the JSP. `location = 'page.jsp';` and so on. By the way, in the JS code in your question you're only printing the parent page, not the popup page...

Comment: In the popup window i can display the values from arraylist and there call window.open();Those values will be print.